# Multiples consultas MySQL (msqli) en un archivo php

Tags: php, mysqli, while

Tengo mi conexión a la bd así

```
$conn = new mysqli(server,user,pass,mainDataBase);
un procedimiento almacenado que devuelve una tabla
$sql = "call sp_escap()";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
y las imprimo en el label
while ($r=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<label href="#collapse'.$r['IdEscenarios'].'" class="nav-toggle">'.$r['NombreEsc'].'</label><br>';
      }
       ?>
```

hasta aquí todo va bien pero 
cuando quiero hacer otra consulta me da el error

> **Warning:** mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

y tengo que comentar mi primer *`while`* para que se pueda ejecutar la seguna consulta.

Ayuda por favor **¿Cómo hacer las dos consultas en el mismo archivo?**

Comment: puedes comentar en tu código lo que no es codigo no se aprecia correctamente. ademas puedes agregar las dos consultas que haces en el mismo archivo. te recomiendo hacer handler de las respuesta de cada consultas en diferentes variables, para luego iterarlas en lls while y evitar problemas de variables repetitivas.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta hacerlo de esta manera. Espero te ayude. Bendiciones.

```
    <?php


            require('conexion.php');
    
            $consultas="SELECT *  FROM alumnos";

            $resultados=$conectahugo->query($consultas);
    
            while($columnas=$resultados->fetch_assoc()){
                        
            echo $columnas['id'],' ';
            echo $columnas['nombrep'],' ';
            echo $columnas['descripcion'],' ';
            echo $columnas['precio'],' ';
            
            
            echo '<br>';
            }
        
?>
```

Yo opino que siempre hay que buscar de Dios. =)

Comment: Siempre al Rey de Reyes y Señor de Señores!! @Carlos

Comment: Amen!!!!! @carlos